# Lion Server:Cannot enable address book server

Tags: macos, osx-server

I bought lion server and would like to set up an address book server to keep contacts synchronized.

With the address-book side panel is selected I click the On/Off switch, which should turn it on.  I then click off that side panel, and back on and nothing it is once again in the off position.  No errors, no feedback nothing.

If there is an error, where would I find the log?  Is there another service in Lion I need to turn on first to enable this?

Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You can always check the logs via the console application, if it is something on this level I would expect to see a few messages popping up when you toggle this.

Comment: Thanks Hobs. I tried this. I looked at the logs in Utilites/Console app, googled them with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So googling the error messages in the Console app didn't yield results.

However googling the generic 'error reading settings' message the Server app was displaying found this page:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3189397?start=0&tstart=0

Basically I had to copy overwrite my httpd.conf file with the original .default version.  Doing this while Server was shutdown and then starting it back up has allowed Address Book, Calendar sever, iChat Sever, and all the rest to start up.

Comment: Select your answer as the correct one, good job finding it!